# Escaping data tips when saving in sql tables

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a somewhat general question.  I am making a read/post news-kind of site/cms and I am not sure how I should go about escaping the data to be saved in the sql tables. Should I just call add slashes before insert and strip slashes after select or is there something else I am missing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to learn about PDO or MySQLi. These were constructed so that injection would cease to be a problem. They're a bit more work than PHP's regular MySQL functions, but those are due to be removed in future versions in PHP, and should really not be encouraged.

The top-voted PHP question on StackOverflow actually concerns exactly this. It's [available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), and the accepted solution described exactly what you need to learn.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Used PDO instead; http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

If you're using PDO you dont need to escape every time you insert into database. PDO have a 'escaping' features.

Read the documentation, will help you with this.

Read this as well, it will help you understand the PDO features etc...
http://marco-pivetta.com/doctrine2-orm-tutorial/#1